# Прокрутить страницы вниз jquery после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

где ошибся? после полной загрузки страницы, нужно прокрутить ее вниз до id

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    let url = location.href;
    const c = 'comment-';

    url = url.slice(-1) === '/' ? url.slice(0, -1) : url;
    const comment = url.split('/').slice(-1)[0];

    console.log(comment)
    console.log(`comment exists = ${comment.startsWith(c) && +comment.replace(c, '') > 0}`)
    if ((comment.startsWith(c) && +comment.replace(c, '') > 0) === true){
        let commentID = url.match(/comment-(\d+)\/$/);
        var id  = comment;
        top = $('#'+id).offset().top;
        console.log(id);
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
    }
})
```

Comment: А в чем ошибка? В консоли что выводится?

Comment: comment exists = true
app.js:55826 comment-226

но не скролит к комменту вниз

Comment: у коммента есть id   и равен   id="comment-226"

Comment: Еще строчка с `id` должна выводиться. Есть такая в консоли? Еще и `top` в консоль выведите.

Comment: да, выводит comment-226

Comment: вот страница http://one.extremje.bget.ru/posts/4444444444/comment-226

Comment: Я ни вижу в консоли ни одного лога. И тем более, вижу, что у вас на странице vue.js Следовательно, решения из jquery могут не работать.

Comment: вот здесь при клике по ссылке работает скрол вниз http://one.extremje.bget.ru/posts/v-rossii-mozhet-popast-pod-zapret-kraftovoe-pivo

Comment: в консоле выводит #comment-226

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99959/discussion-between-uvasya-and-stepan-kasyanenko).